# VS Pair to mac - fails to ssh

Tags: macos, visual-studio, ssh

When I'm trying pair to my mac, I get the following: `An error occurred while trying to establish an SSH connection with SSH keys to 'IP'`. However, using ssh to connect to my mac through cmd it works just fine but for some reason VS fails to do this.

Comment: I have the same problem.  People report that modifying sshd_config worked for them but that initially didn't work for me.  Then it worked after I restarted VS.  More info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215881/vs-2022-wont-connect-with-mac-after-ventura-upgrade/74221115

Comment: @AlexKay Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction. It worked! :)

Comment: glad it helped!  Please mark my recommendation as the answer so that it can help others.

Comment: @AlexKay I apologize for the delay! Could you perhaps post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it

Comment: Sure, I just did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works is following these steps:

1. Add these lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
   ```
2. Save the file.
3. Restart `sshd`.
4. Restart Visual Studio.

The original recipe was provided here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216924/117259).