# How to clone/push private repo on github?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have created a private repo on github, I want to clone this (empty) repo to my local computer to push changes to.

I'm using MacOS Ventura 13.0.

I have created a keypair and I have uploaded the public key to `Settings > SSH and GPG keys`. [I have added this key to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). When I [test my SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) to GitHub, everything works as expected (I get the preferred output like my username and stuff).

When I try to clone the private repo, I get the following output:

```
user@my-mac <folder> % git clone git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
Cloning into '<folder>'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What could possibly be wrong? Should I add the SSH key to a specific repo (in deploy keys)?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has a page for this error message: [Permission denied (publickey)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Walking through the steps listed there probably will fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you have MacOS Ventura, you must

- (easy way) to forgot about RSA signatures using SHA-1 and use another stronger type, [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74216924/960558)

> Starting with OpenSSH v8.8, RSA signatures using SHA-1 are disabled

- (hard way) RSA signatures using SHA-1 can be re-enabled, if you can edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and do some other tricks, as it was [already outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74215881/960558) some tome ago

Comment: What `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has in common with `git clone git@github.com`?