# Visual Studio 2019 pair to mac stuck at "Checking ssh configuration"

Tags: macos, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I know this issue has been posted before, but the solutions didn´t really help me.

I´m working on a Xamarin App and I need a mac to test my Application there. I updated the Mac OS to Mac OS Ventura. Since then, I can´t pair Visual Studio 2019(on Windows) with my Mac. [This step doesn´t continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNypS.png)

I`ve added all the things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215881/visual-studio-2022-wont-connect-via-ssh-on-macos-after-upgrading-to-ventura). But it doesn´t seem to work. Has anyone an idea what I've to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solutions below:

1.Ugrade your Visual Studio to 2022 and try `Xcode 14`(not 14.1, download Xcode 14.0 from the [downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/) in the Apple Developer Portal). Then open Xcode and go to **Xcode->Preferences->Location->Command Line Tools and select 14.0**.

2.[Clear the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac).

3.Check that your firewall allows and ping the IP on your Windows machine, and check if the Mac is routable from the Windows computer.

4.Delete the configuration file of your Mac and reboot your Mac, please see the 8-12 steps in the following doc- [Connection Troubleshooting for a Xamarin.iOS Build Host - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting)

Comment: Upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 did the trick for me. All other troubleshooting steps failed.