# VS 2022 17.5.1 wont find mac

Tags: xamarin, maui

This had been working before I updated Visual Studio to 17.5.1 today(I was on 17.4 previously).  After the update, My Mac will show up in visual studio but after it tries to connect it says host unreachable.  I am able to ssh to the Mac using both the hostname and the ip address and run a remote command sucessfully such as ssh jtest@m-1 'ls'.  It seems similar to this problem: [SSH Connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215881/visual-studio-2022-wont-connect-via-ssh-on-macos-after-upgrading-to-ventura) and I tried everything in there- but it still says host unreachable.  The version of MAC OS is 13.2.1.

Comment: Do you have some detailed error logs? You can try the solution in [Connection Troubleshooting for a Xamarin.iOS Build Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#couldnt-connect-to-macbuildhostlocal-please-try-again) first.

Comment: Thank you for the tip- I did try everything in that article as well.  Two additional things- When the screen to select a MAC shows up- my mac is listed along with an old mac I have not had in years.  When I click connect- they both say host unreachable.  I disbaled the firewall on the Mac as well- but no change.  I dont see anything in the logs- but if there is a secure place I can post them I will.

Comment: What was the version number of XCode before you updated VS, and have you updated XCode since then.

Comment: The version of XCode is 14.2.  I have not updated it since updating VS.

Comment: You can report the problem to VS, during which you can roll back to the previous version for normal use.

Comment: I have done as suggested and posted at Microsoft here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/After-Visual-Studio-1751-update-Xamari/10301221  I will update here once I hace a solution.

Comment: Ok, waiting for your updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received an answer from Microsoft.  They indicated that in the connection dialog, it now does a ping on the Mac before attempting the ssh connection.  If the ping is unsuccessful- it will say host is unreachable.

I enabled ping on my Mac and then was able to connect.  I am not happy with this- as I dont like ping on my machine and it is a horrible way to verify connectivity.

I upgraded to the latest- 17.5.3 and it has the same behavior.

To save the Google\Bing\Whatever search- here is how to enable ping on the Mac(At least on Ventura 13.2.1):

- Click Apple icon in the upper left and select System Settings
- Click Network
- Click Options
- Click the toggle button next to "Enable Stealth mode" - it should be greyed out now
- After this- I had to click the toggle for Firewall off and on

Close Visual Studio and reopen Visual Studio and was able to connect.  If it still doesn't work- try rebooting both PC and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an update based on the [developer community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/After-Visual-Studio-1751-update-Xamari/10301221) in the comment to the question.

It is now possible to tell Visual Studio to not use ping to check reachability from the options. This is the specific reply which mentions this, and here it is in case the link becomes dead in the future:

> A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. A new option in Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings has been added to enable/disable host reachability checks. The default value is enabled, however the users that were already using the environment variable will preserve the chosen value. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download.