# How does VS determine which SSH instance and arguments to use

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a Windows Server 2016 machine running Visual Studio 2022 17.6.3 that we use to build our Xamarin projects.  We recently upgraded our macOS to Ventura and since have not been able to pair Visual Studio to the mac.  I have followed the [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting) from Microsoft to no avail.

I have also run through the solutions offered in [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74201038/pair-to-mac-error-failed-to-execute-grep-ssh-rsa) stackoverflow question but have not been able to resolve the issue.

I also have multiple Win10 and Win11 machines running Visual Studio 2022 17.6.3 where the Mac pairs successfully.

I don't know if Win2016 is related or not but there is a difference between the arguments used by Visual Studio on machines where it pairs successfully.

When it **doesn't pair** the logs show that VS is attempting to use *rsa*:

> Executing SSH command 'ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -m PEM -f "/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/<guid1>" -q -N "<guid2>"'...

When it **does pair** the logs show that VS is using *ecdsa*:

> Executing SSH command: 'ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 521 -m PEM -f "/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/<guid1>" -N "<guid2>" -q'

Something is making the same version of VS behave differently. I presume that VS is somehow making a decision about which ssh.exe file to use and then making a determination about which parameters to use based on that but I have no insight into that and I have been thwarted in my attempts to prove that.

I've tried:

1. installing the latest version of OpenSSH;
2. renaming every instance of ssh.exe until I find which one it's using and then replacing that one with the latest version;
3. removing all but the latest version of OpenSSH; and
4. updating the path environment variable to point only to the instance of ssh.exe I want it to use.

Does anyone have an information about how VS determines:

1. which ssh.exe instance to use; and
2. how it determines which arguments to use when attempting to run ssh-keygen?